# What is the difference between TE and TI?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, instrumentation

I have done some research about the subject but I can't find the difference between Temperature Element (**TE**) and  Temperature Indicator (**TI**) 
[image]

Here is an image of the P&ID of the project am working on if it can help clarify my question.

Comment: ...and what have you found in your research?

Comment: that is they are  both instrument of temperature measurement, but i dont know what is the key difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element does the measuring and the indicator shows the value.

If you think of a simple thermometer, the bulb at the bottom measures the temperature and the glass tube indicates the value...

Comment: well in the exampl that i have, there is a TE with TW ( thermowell ) and  the TI is also accompanied with a TW even thou he only indicate the value ?

Comment: @AzedS The TI (or the reference/cold junction) needs to be at a known temperature in order to solve the simple linear equations that Seebeck effects demand. An easy way to keep something at a known temperature is to place it in a bath of liquid/use a triple point of water cell or a thermowell. You can also use cold junction compensation, though and even some NMI labs use this.

Answer (score 0):

Temperature indicator consists of two parts: the first part is  the temperature element itself and the second part is the electronic part that conditions the signal and convert it to 4 to 20  and then send it to control system .

Answer (score 0):

TI = Temperature Indicator; Shows temperature local (in pipe, canal, wall, …)
TT = Temperature Transmitter; Remote monitoring temp. (0-10V, 4-20mA, ...)
TE = Temperature Element; Remote monitoring temp. by resitance (Pt100, NTC 5k, ...)

TTI = Temperature Transmitter Indicator; Remote monitoring temp. with display

PT = Pressure Transmitter
TA = Temperature Alarm
TAh = Tempreature high Alarm
FI = Flow Indicator
QTrh = Quality Transmitter relative humidity